# How to duplicate Navigation Controller image on other View Controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I had a View Controller. Later I embed it in Navigation Controller and in the navigation bar I add view panel with the imageView inside. Now, can I make that this view->imageView will show on all other viewControllers too? Now I have this just in main navigation controller and in the other controllers I don't have it.

I did try to put to all of them manually, but in some viewControllers I couldn't put view panel to navigation panel. What is the problem?

Comment: You can set the `appearance` of navigationBar to get it globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `UINavigationBar` appearance as,

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This change will affect all navigationBar in your application scope.

In Swift,

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "nav_bg.png"), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Comment: can you write it in `Swift`?

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade Please check my updated answer. Set it from your `applicationDelegate` or some global class.